# Error 522 with Cloudflare

Tags: mysql, linux, ssl, debian, cloudflare

Hello I have always error 522 with Cloudflare and SSL
I use 2 url the first is via Cloudflare with full ssl https://example.com and second is with my ip and without Cloudflare http://XXX.XXX. If i start benchmaking `mysql` with AB command (or with simple ajax request) the siteweb with Cloudflare down imediatly with error 522 but the website with my IP never down and continue to work faster

I have a free plan in Cloudflare with a auto signed SSL certificat in my server with openssl

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/s1.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/s1.crt
```

I changed my.cnf for limit max_user_connections to 20 but not working i dont have error in apache and syslog

My server is a debian 7 3 cores 4gb in OVH

top

```
top - 07:26:58 up 15:25,  2 users,  load average: 2.23, 2.28, 2.18
Tasks:  57 total,   2 running,  55 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  8.1 us,  1.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 88.7 id,  2.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   4194304 total,   354532 used,  3839772 free,        0 buffers
KiB Swap:   131072 total,        0 used,   131072 free,   159668 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
11715 mysql     20   0  585m 100m 7824 S  28.1  2.5 117:17.15 mysqld
14469 www-data  20   0  222m  12m 4312 R   2.9  0.3   0:20.86 apache2
14567 www-data  20   0  222m  11m 3604 S   2.0  0.3   0:12.89 apache2
14579 www-data  20   0  221m  11m 3612 S   2.0  0.3   0:07.69 apache2
 2599 root      20   0 24364 2208 1296 S   1.0  0.1  10:53.41 htop
 5317 root      20   0 24292 2184 1296 S   0.7  0.1  10:41.42 htop
14577 www-data  20   0  221m  10m 3400 S   0.7  0.3   0:08.94 apache2
    1 root      20   0 10604  796  664 S   0.0  0.0   0:15.10 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd/46179
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper/46179
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/46179/0
    5 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/46179/1
    6 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/46179/2
    7 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/46179/3
    8 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/46179/4
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/46179/5
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/46179/6
   11 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/46179/7
   12 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 nfsiod/46179
 1533 root      20   0 30764  488  244 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 syslog-ng
 1534 root      20   0 88480 3572 2480 S   0.0  0.1   0:02.10 syslog-ng
 1658 messageb  20   0 29760  556  296 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 dbus-daemon
 1676 bind      20   0  202m  22m 2324 S   0.0  0.5   0:02.13 named
 1682 root      20   0 49888 1236  628 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.37 sshd
 1717 root      20   0 72552 2132  524 S   0.0  0.1   0:19.69 sendmail-mta
 2295 root      20   0 20844 1024  776 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.76 cron
 2398 proftpd   20   0 99.7m 1944  500 S   0.0  0.0   0:09.15 proftpd
 2422 root      20   0 52324 1672 1152 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 login
 2423 root      20   0 14532  836  676 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 getty
 2424 root      20   0 14532  832  676 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 getty
 2425 root      20   0 14532  828  676 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 getty
 2426 root      20   0 14532  832  676 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 getty
 2427 root      20   0 14532  832  676 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 getty
 2506 root      20   0 24368 1964  776 S   0.0  0.0   0:46.24 screen
 2507 root      20   0 19944 2272 1672 S   0.0  0.1   0:02.25 bash
 2508 root      20   0 19916 2176 1604 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.02 bash
 5316 root      20   0 19916 2176 1604 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 bash
 9522 root      20   0  220m  10m 4436 S   0.0  0.3   0:36.96 apache2
10166 root      20   0 19924 2216 1636 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 bash
```

Answer (score 1):

A 522 error generally indicates something blocking requests from our IPs on your server or hosting provider.

[Additional troubleshooting tips for a 522 error and CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171906-Error-522-Connection-timed-out).